# How to split a large file to small files and files named by column

Tags: bash, shell, awk

this is my csv input, record.csv

```
AAAAA_01|2020-12-28
BBBBB_01|2021-05-24
CCCCC_01|2021-05-17
DDDDD_01|2021-05-19
EEEEE_01|2021-05-20
FFFFF_01|2021-05-30
GGGGG_01|2021-05-25
HHHHH_01|2020-12-23
```

hope I can split the csv into below txt and named with column 1 name (only first 5 character)

AAAAA.txt

```
Name: AAAAA
Date: 2020-12-28
```

BBBBB.txt

```
Name: BBBBB
Date: 2021-05-24
```

I tried below script, file name exported as xaa,xab......
but no idea how to rename it into my desired name...

```
cat record.csv | awk 'BEGIN{FS="|";OFS="|"
}{ 
print "Name: "substr($1,1,5)
print "Date:" $2

}'| split -l 12
```

Thanks!

---

```
awk -F'|' '                                    
 f=substr($1,1,5)".txt"                                    
{
print "Name: "substr($1,1,5) >f
print "Date: "$2 >f
print "Remarks" >f
close(f)  
}
' record.csv
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to `cat` into `awk`, or pipe to something else. `awk` can do all of this for you.  You can print to files using normal redirection syntax and quoting the filename.

```
awk -F'|' '{name=substr($1,1,5); print "Name: "name ORS "Date:" $2 > name".txt"}' abcde.txt
```

e.g.

```
$ ls
 abcde.txt

$ cat abcde.txt
 AAAAA_01|2020-12-28
 BBBBB_01|2021-05-24
 CCCCC_01|2021-05-17
 DDDDD_01|2021-05-19
 EEEEE_01|2021-05-20
 FFFFF_01|2021-05-30
 GGGGG_01|2021-05-25
 HHHHH_01|2020-12-23

$ awk -F'|' '{name=substr($1,1,5); print "Name: "name ORS "Date:" $2 > name".txt"}' 
 abcde.txt

$ ls
 AAAAA.txt  abcde.txt  BBBBB.txt  CCCCC.txt  DDDDD.txt  
 EEEEE.txt  FFFFF.txt  GGGGG.txt  HHHHH.txt

$ cat AAAAA.txt
 Name: AAAAA
 Date:2020-12-28
$ cat BBBBB.txt
 Name: BBBBB
 Date:2021-05-24
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Since it may add more row in the future, could I know how to  split into multiple lines after "print"? likes, 1st row: "Name:" name, 2nd row: "Date:" $2, 3rd row: "Remarks:"

Comment: by referencing both ans, I added my solution in the bottom, will any much more clever ways for future editing? may be add much more line in the future

Answer (score 2):

Sample input:

```
$ cat record.csv
AAAAA_01|2020-12-28
BBBBB_01|2021-05-24
CCCCC_01|2021-05-17
DDDDD_01|2021-05-19
EEEEE_01|2021-05-20
FFFFF_01|2021-05-30
GGGGG_01|2021-05-25
HHHHH_01|2020-12-23
```

One `awk` solution:

```
$ awk -F'[_|]' '                                    # define underscore (_) and pipe (|) as input delimiters
{ f=$1".txt"                                        # define output file name (f) as $1.txt
  printf "Name: %s\nDate: %s\n", $1, $3 > f         # format data as desired and write to output file (f)
  close(f)                                          # close the output file (some versions of awk will crash if too many file descriptors are kept open at the same time)
}
' record.csv
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
$ awk -F'[_|]' '{ f=$1".txt" ; printf "Name: %s\nDate: %s\n", $1, $3 > f; close(f)}' record.csv
```

The above generates the following:

```
$ ls -1 [A-Z]????.txt
AAAAA.txt
BBBBB.txt
CCCCC.txt
DDDDD.txt
EEEEE.txt
FFFFF.txt
GGGGG.txt
HHHHH.txt

$ for fname in [A-Z]????.txt
do
    echo "++++++++++++ ${fname}"
    cat "${fname}"
done
++++++++++++ AAAAA.txt
Name: AAAAA
Date: 2020-12-28
++++++++++++ BBBBB.txt
Name: BBBBB
Date: 2021-05-24
++++++++++++ CCCCC.txt
Name: CCCCC
Date: 2021-05-17
++++++++++++ DDDDD.txt
Name: DDDDD
Date: 2021-05-19
++++++++++++ EEEEE.txt
Name: EEEEE
Date: 2021-05-20
++++++++++++ FFFFF.txt
Name: FFFFF
Date: 2021-05-30
++++++++++++ GGGGG.txt
Name: GGGGG
Date: 2021-05-25
++++++++++++ HHHHH.txt
Name: HHHHH
Date: 2020-12-23
```